# ASP.Net MS IIS 10 сайт недоступен с сервера, но доступен с интернета

Tags: iis-10

Имеется ПК с установленной на него Windows Server 2022 и развёрнутым IIS 10 сервером. Имеется сайт с адресом (например!) example.com. С внешнего компьютера я на сайт зайти могу и он корректно работает, а с браузера, установленного на самом ПК -- нет. Выдаёт: `DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN`

Comment: по IP удаётся открыть сайт?

Comment: на ip у меня 3 сайта висит. И через него не входит...

Comment: попробуйте через localhost

Comment: Не открывает ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

Comment: посмотрите гайд с картинками, проверьте у себя настройки сайта https://manage.accuwebhosting.com/knowledgebase/2886/How-to-Configure-IIS-to-Access-Your-Website-using-an-IP-Address.html

Comment: Сайт был действующим. Проблемы начались, когда я поставил другой адрес сайта.  example.com -> example.ru. В DNS нового адреса A прописал.

Comment: сложно что-то понять, но смотрите nslookup  и tracert. явно что-то с DNS у вас

Comment: при использовании tracert выдаёт: Не удается разрешить системное имя узла. С внешнего трасировка идеально проходит